# How to make a network be fail-deadly upon physical tampering?

Tags: home-networking, access-control

I wish to no longer allow my roommate usage of my internet line. While the router I have gives me surprisingly powerful administrative control over my network, any blocks I put in place can be circumvented by using the reset button to return everything to default. I cannot at this moment physically secure the router, nor can I guard it 24/7. *Edit:* The router must remain operational, as there are others who make use of it. I would also like to avoid physically modifying the hardware, as it belongs to the ISP (I've thought about gluing the reset button with something that can only be unglued by a specific "key" solvent, or some other time-consuming but reversible mod).

Being an IT guy/computer nerd, I have plenty of computing equipment available to me and the knowledge to be dangerous with it. The adversary is non-technical; they could not reconfigure a router or a proxy server, for example, but they can perform actions such as factory resets, powering off/unplugging equipment, and etc. They also cannot call the ISP for access to perform changes via that route.

How can I configure my network such that if the adversary attempts to factory reset the router or any other piece of equipment to regain access while I am away, the Internet will become non-functional/unusable until additional manual configuration is performed (ie. by me)?

> This is a technical question and I am seeking a technical approach to
>   doing this, the social interaction between my roommate and I is
>   irrelevant to the scope of the question.

One possibility I've thought of would be to change the factory defaults so the info printed on the label (eg. SSID and key) is then invalid. This doesn't prevent another party from sharing the key with them however, and I don't want to have to update the key on a regular basis. Surely there's a more elegant approach.

Comment: You could start by 1/ removing/obscuring the label on the router. Hopefully your roommate doesn't have the info written down. 2/ buy another router, remove the  label and don't share the key with anybody. 3/ take your router with you when you are not in the room 4/ evict your roommate

Comment: 5/ put superglue in the reset button.

Comment: Get new roommates who have some respect for you.

Comment: Does the router need to stay online when you are away? If not just take the poweradaptor with you.

Comment: open up the router and use a soldering iron to remove the reset button.

Comment: followed up with MAC address white listing.

Comment: Could you you set the router to blacklist his MAC addresses then lock it in a cupboard? That said I think that you might have other issues that need addressing...

Comment: @acejavelin I wholeheartedly agree... This person is my co-tenant however, so I can't get rid of them so easily.

Comment: @Tonny The router needs to be online and operational for the use of others, plus my own remote access.

Comment: @DavidPostill The network key would be saved on their devices anyways, so that's no good. It belongs to the ISP anyways. Hmmm... call tech support and swap routers! But I don't think I'm allowed to scratch off the label.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 Ah, I see (and I noticed a hardware mod is out of the question). Anyway: You have a social problem, if you can't trust your co-tenant not to mess with your stuff.

Comment: @Tonny I mean, they aren't gonna be too thrilled when I cut off their Internet access. I know I would go straight for the router.

Comment: Have you thought about physically locking your router in box? That way you don't have to mod the router and your bad roommate won't have access to the reset button.

Answer (score 1):

The reset button is usually setup so there isn't a way to bypass it without physically modifying the device.

Usually an ISP will let you use your own router. Buy one, preferably the same make and model, and use that and return the ISP owned device. Then proceed with the hardware mods such as super-gluing or physically removing the reset button mechanism (de-soldering the switch or removing a mechanical piece if possible). If you want to get particularly creative or need the switch available, replace it with something else. A Hall sensor, magnetic switch, or reed relay might be used with an external magnet (keep out of sight of your roommate as its easy to deduce what's going on once seen in action).

Comment: With your own device, you could even load a custom firmware, making the "factory reset" configuration identical to your preferred custom configuration. Then, if the adversary pushes the reset button, no need to disable the internet for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems he is the guy who feels entitled to "his" internet no matter what.
But it isn't his. It's yours.
Co-tenant or not. If he uses the internet without your permission (even worse, messes with your equipment, like doing a factory reset) he is technically guilty of theft and/or vandalism.
He probably won't see it that way... And if you confront him with that things could turn very ugly, very quickly.

So I would play it the other way. Give him a guest-wifi SSID on the router AND allow him to use that to his hearts content, but it is going to cost him 50% of the internet bill.
(Don't even call it a "guest"-wifi, to sweeten the deal. Call it "Mike's personal internet" or something like that.)
You can probably restrict the bandwidth he gets in your own router. And most reasonably modern routers that allow a guest-wifi setup keep the traffic on that separate from the main LAN.
(Added benefit: If there is ever an dispute about who did what on the connection, like downloading copyrighted material or something like that, this setup (and the router logs) gives you some plausibility that it was him doing the dirty deed, not you.)

If this is technically not feasible with the ISP router you've got, you can easily setup a 2nd router as the "guest" device and put that as a slave device behind the real ISP router: Same solution in a slightly different form.

In short: don't fight it, but give him is own personal playpen to keep him out of your hair.

Comment: -1, Thanks for your input, but that is counterproductive to my goal.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 I understand your point, but any technical solution depends heavily on the ability to secure the router (placing it behind lock and key or making the software config really permanent). The only other option I see is social: Modify the opponents behavior.